# accessing a strings elements using [] prints random results

Tags: c++, string

So, I am making a mid square hashing function as part of a project for school, and I am perplexed how my computer is taking two random string elements out of a string when I am only asking for one element. Here is a tiny example in code below.

```
string squaredKey = "54756";
int middleDigit = (ceil(stringSquareKey.length()/2));
cout << squaredKey[middleDigit] << endl; // this prints out 7 as expected
string temp = to_string(squaredKey[middleDigit]);
cout << temp << endl; // This prints out 55 for some reason.
```

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but I think it has something to do with `to_string()`. Let me know if you would like to see more code.

Comment: Unrelated: `stringSquareKey.length()/2` is 100% integer math. `ceil` is not useful here. The value has already been floored by truncation.

Comment: Because `'7' != 7`

Comment: 55 is numeric value of character '7'

Answer (score 1):

[`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is for converting *numbers* to strings. And an unfortunate fact of C++ is that `char` is also a number in its own right, though it's commonly used to represent ASCII values.

What `to_string(squaredKey[middleDigit]);` is doing is taking the ASCII value `'7'` (**not** `7`) and converting it to a decimal number, which is 55.

You should use the `std::string` constructor that accepts a `char` and a count:

```
std::string temp(1, squaredKey[middleDigit]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::to_string` converts a numeric value to `std::string`, so its input is treated as a numeric value. `stringSquareKey.length()/2` gives character value `'7'`, which corresponds - when treated as a numeric value - to ASCII code `55`.

So your code is the same as `string temp = to_string(55)`.